# How to get maximum value for each group?

Tags: r

In the data frame(df), I need to insert a new column for each group of **Sl** defining its maximum **Value**.

```
df=data.frame(
  Sl= c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5),
Value= c(0,2,1,3,5,2,5,8,10,3,5,7)    
)

#Expected outcome:
df$col3=c(2,2,5,5,5,5,5,10,10,7,7,7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `max` by group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(col3 = max(Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `ave`

```
dfout <- within(df, col3 <- ave(Value,Sl,FUN = max))
```